# How does the user control behave asynchronously if vb6 doesn't have threading?

Tags: vb6

As outlined in [this well known article.](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/03/27/simple-asynchronous-downloads.aspx).

As I understand it, threading is something that happens in a single process where the appearance of multiple processes executing simultaneously is given by a sort of sharing of the single thread in rotation.

If vb6 doesn't facilitate this how can a vb6 program do 2 things simultaneously?

Answer (score 4):

As far as doing 2 things at once goes... it does and it doesn't.

100% of the code you normally write in VB6 runs on the User Interface thread as an event handler.  These are expected to run to do a bit of work and then return back to the main message loop that "lives in" the runtime and sleeps awaiting requests when the message queue is empty.

Many components typically written in C++ have worker threads within them that can run in parallel.  These normally trigger COM events or callbacks or send a window message to the VB6 program's hidden topmost window, which gets picked up and dispatched by the message loop to the approriate event handler or callback routine.  System events can also send window messages, which is how things like keystrokes and mouse actions get to your VB6 programs.

This isn't that far off from how *any* Windows Subsystem program operates no matter what language it is written in.  The only substantial difference is that you can't trivially create ad hoc worker threads of your own in VB6.

Low level API callbacks are another matter, and can indeed result in VB6 code running on a worker thread.  When not used carefully this can be hazardous since such threads often don't even have COM initialized on them, which can result in a nasty crash if you try to execute VB6 statements that require it (and quite a few *do*).